# Where Condition with complicated logic

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table which looks something like this...

**ID        ColumnA         ColumnB         ColumnC** 

1            ALL                 ALL             ALL  
2            A                     ALL             ALL  
3            A                       B              ALL  
4            A                       B              C

Here "ALL" is nothing but a default value.

So in the SELECT statement if my Condition is ColumnA='D' and  ColumnB='D' and ColumnC='D' then it should return the first row (ID=1)

If Condition is ColumnA='A' and  ColumnB='B' and ColumnC='D' then it should return the third row (ID=3)

How can we implement this without reading the table multiple times?

Comment: add an OR for every condition..

Comment: i want one row.. the nearest match .. Not all the rows

Comment: What rdbms are you using at all?

Comment: I'm using Oracle.

Comment: The rules are incomplete. Do you check column A first? Does matching on column A but not matching on B and C have higher priority than matching on B and C but not on A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this works, at least it does in SQL-Server (have no oracle):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM
(
    SELECT ID, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,
           CASE WHEN (ColumnA=@col1 AND ColumnB=@col2 AND ColumnC=@col3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As BestMatch,
           CASE WHEN (ColumnA=@col1 AND ColumnB=@col2 AND ColumnC='ALL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As SecondBestMatch,
           CASE WHEN (ColumnA=@col1 AND ColumnB='ALL' AND ColumnC='ALL') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As ThirdBestMatch
    FROM dbo.Table_Name
) x
ORDER BY BestMatch DESC, SecondBestMatch DESC, ThirdBestMatch DESC, ID ASC
```

I think in oracle you need to replace the `TOP 1` with `where rownum = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your select statement:

```
  100*CASE WHEN ColA=VALUE1 THEN 2 WHEN ColA='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   + 10*CASE WHEN ColB=VALUE2 THEN 2 WHEN ColB='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   + 1*CASE WHEN ColC=VALUE3 THEN 2 WHEN ColC='ALL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SortOrder
```

Then order by it DESC and select top 1 row where SortOrder > 0.

Im from MSSQL so oracle-syntax might be different but the principle should work.

Answer (score 0):

Select all rows that match the criteria. Then rank them and keep the best row. In case of a tie, we pick one of the best rows arbitrarily.

As of Oracle 12c:

```
select id, columna, columnb, columnc
from mytable
where columna in ('A', 'ALL')
  and columnb in ('B', 'ALL')
  and columnc in ('D', 'ALL')
order by 
  case when columna = 'A' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when columnb = 'B' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when columnc = 'D' then 1 else 0 end desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions:

```
select id, columna, columnb, columnc
from
(
  select
    id, columna, columnb, columnc,
    row_number() over (order by 
      case when columna = 'A' then 1 else 0 end +
      case when columnb = 'B' then 1 else 0 end +
      case when columnc = 'D' then 1 else 0 end desc) as rn
  from mytable
  where columna in ('A', 'ALL')
    and columnb in ('B', 'ALL')
    and columnc in ('D', 'ALL')
) where rn = 1;
```

Comment: You could remove some of the hard coding by using `case when columna != 'ALL' then ...` (and did the cases need to have the column names updating? they're currently all columna?)

Comment: @Boneist: Thanks, there where copy & paste mistakes. It's columna for 'A', columnb for 'B' and columnc for 'D'.

Answer (score -1):

Will this not get you what you want?

```
(ColumnA='D' or ColumnnA='ALL') 
 and (ColumnB='D' or ColumnB='ALL')
 and (ColumnC='D' or ColumnC='ALL')
```

(EDIT)

To get a 'best match' there may be more than one, then apply an order by as follows and select the first row.

```
order by
    case when ColumnA='ALL' then 0 else 1 end
      + case when ColumnB='ALL' then 0 else 1 end
      + case when ColumnB='ALL' then 0 else 1 end DESC
```

Comment: No, he wants one row, the best matching